# error with scikit-learn when using scikit-neuralnetwork

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install scikit-neuralnetwork folloing instructions from section **Install sknn** in https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-with-scikit-learn-1de142d96118

As firt step, I installed scikit-neuralnetwork as follows:

```
!pip install scikit-neuralnetwork
```

As nest step, I tried to import Classifier, Layer from sknn.mlp as follows:

from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer

However, I have the next output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d293861858aa> in <module>()
----> 1 from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sknn/mlp.py in <module>()
     20 import sklearn.pipeline
     21 import sklearn.preprocessing
---> 22 import sklearn.cross_validation
     23 
     24 from .nn import NeuralNetwork, Layer, Convolution, Native, ansi

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Since, this method didn't work, then I try to follow section **B) Pulling Repositories [Optional]** in https://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_installation.html#a-download-latest-release-recommended,

This corresponds to the following steps:

```
!pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/master/requirements.txt
!git clone https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork.git
!cd scikit-neuralnetwork; python setup.py develop
```

but, I had exactly the same error  when I tried to import Classifier, Layer from sknn.mlp as follows.

Comment: The scikit-neuralnetwork code hasn't been updated in 4 years. Since then, `sklearn.cross_validation` has been renamed to `sklearn.model_selection`. See https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/issues/242

Comment: It is indeed puzzling why an article of August 2020 would advise using a project that has been effectively abandoned since 2016, hence creating incompatibility issues with newer versions such as the one you report here. My advice: don't bother.